# Prove that all the roots lie inside a little circle |z|=r, for n large enough

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

$$f(z)= 1 + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2!z^2} + ... + \frac{1}{n!z^n}$$

I can't seem to apply Rouche's Theorem here.

Another idea would be to use perhaps Big Picard's theorem, since f(z) will converge to $e^{\large \frac{1}{z}}$, I think.  And so it will have an essential singularity at z=0.

But Big Picard allows for one exceptional point.  What if the exceptional point is...0?  Then I am stuck.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: What was the problem with Rouche's theorem?

Comment: Hint: $f(z)$ has all root inside circle $|z| = r$ is equivalent to $f(1/z)$ has no root inside the circle $|z| = \frac1r$.

Comment: Hi @achillehui - did you mean radius $r$ or $\frac{1}{r}$ for the second circle?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001 I mean radius $\frac1r$ for the circle in new coordinate $w = \frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: Hi @achillehui, hmmm...so we want f(z) to have all its roots lie inside a little circle |z|<r.  So we want all $z_k$ such that $f(z_k)=0$ for which $|z_k|<r$ for $1\le k \le n$.  Then $\frac{1}{|z_k|}>\frac{1}{r}$, and so $f(\frac{1}{z})$ has its roots *outside* of the disk $|z|<\frac{1}{r}$.  So, by inverting the argument that $f$ takes, we push its roots to different locations.

Comment: Is my thinking correct so far?  Now for $n$ "large enough", $f(z)$ is approximately $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$.  Then $f(\frac{1}{z})$ is approximately $e^z$, whose only root is at $-\infty$, or simply, the "point at infinity".  So, $f(\frac{1}{z})$ has no roots inside of a very large circle $|z|=\frac{1}{r}$, so here $r$ is very small.  Then by the argument in the beginning, we know that the location of the roots of $f(z)$ are now inside a very small circle $|z|=r$.  And this completes the proof.  What do you think?  Am I missing anything?  Do I need to be more precise somewhere?

Comment: Thanks so much,  (p.s., I see a solution below that shows that Rouche's Theorem can indeed be applied, so I will study it now, too, but I would love to hear more from you on this geometrically intuitive proof...) @achillehui

Comment: @User001 Your idea is basically correct, the answer by ts375_zk26 is what you need to do.

Comment: Hi @achillehui, now I have most of the proof worked out except for this last part, which I am concerned may not be true:  using Rouche's Thm, and letting g(z) = $e^z$, and choosing n large enough, epsilon can be arbitrarily small, but the bound $\epsilon < |e^z|$ on the large circle doesn't seem to be true.  Take for example, $e^{-x}$.  On an arbitrarily large circle, this tends toward 0.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: ...so that I want to say, for n large enough, $|f(\frac{1}{z}) - g(z)|<\epsilon < |e^z| = |g(z)|$ for all $z$ on the circle $|z|=R$, but the second inequality doesn't necessarily seem to hold...@achillehui,

Comment: For large $n \gg R$, $|f(\frac1z) - e^{z}|$ is dominated by the first term $\frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ in the expansion (at least on the boundary $|z| = R$),  you essentially need to choose a $n$ such that $\frac{R^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ is smaller than $e^{-R}$ (by some constant factor).

Comment: Ah, right.  Ok got it -- thanks so much for your time, @achillehui.  Have a great Happy New Year in HK :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using Rouche's theorem we prove that for arbitrary large $R$, there exists $n$ such that $$f(1/z)=1+\sum_{k=1}^n z^k/k!\ne 0$$ inside $|z|=R, \,$ that is, $f(1/z)$ has all roots outside $|z|=R\,(=1/r)$.
It is all we shall prove.

Since the series $1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k/k!$ converges to $e^z$ uniformly on $|z|\le R $, $$\left|-\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty z^k/k!\right|<\varepsilon \quad  (|z|\le R)$$
for sufficiently large $n$.
Take $\varepsilon =e^{-R}$, then since $\min_{|z|=R} |e^z|=e^{-R}$  we have $$
\left|-\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty z^k/k!\right|< |e^z|$$
on $|z|=R$.
Therefore by  Rouche's theorem $e^z$ and $f(1/z)=e^z+\left(-\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty z^k/k!\right)$ have the same number of zeros,  that is, $f(1/z)$  has no zeros inside $|z|=R$.

Comment: Hi @ts375_zk26, thanks so much for your answer.  I've worked out the details and can follow along for the most part, but I'm am just little confused with one part of your proof: is it necessary to specify the (arbitrary) epsilon in that way?  Or, can we simply conclude that, letting $g(z) = e^z$, $|f(z)-g(z)|<\epsilon < |e^z| = |g(z)|$? (And therefore, Rouche's Theorem is applicable.) So, I am a little unsure of my second inequality...thanks,

Comment: In the first inequality, I meant to write $|f(\frac{1}{z}) - g(z)|$ ...

Comment: Although, I think the weak inequality can be made true, with the way you are specifying the epsilon, but for Rouche's Theorem, we need the inequality to be strict... @ts375_zk26,

Comment: To apply Rouche's theorem we  need to show that 
$$
|f(1/z)-e^z|=\left|-\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty z^k/k!\right|<e^{-R}\le |e^z|\quad (|z|=R).$$
(The part $<e^{-R}$ is strict, I think.)
Then $e^z+(f(1/z)-e^z)=f(1/z)$ and $e^z$ have the same number of zeros inside $|z|\le R$, that is, $f(1/z)$ has no zeros inside $|z|=R$.